# find two similar rows that starts with the same string in a specific column

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I have a table containing a varchar column in sql server 2008...
I want to find two similar rows that starts with the same string in this specific column...

Comment: please include sample of the table(s) and required output

Comment: You want to compare a single character or a full string with (n) size of characters?